# Detecting ctrl+z (and other control combos) in paper.js

Tags: javascript, keyevent, undo, paperjs, ctrl

I'm trying to enable editing commands in my paper.js application (such as <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> for 'undo').

Detecting individual letter keys works great, and I can detect modifier keys that are held during mouse events, but I'm having trouble writing an event handler that detects combinations of <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and letter keys.

Based on [the examples given by fabric.js](http://paperjs.org/tutorials/interaction/keyboard-interaction/), what I would expect is a key handler that looks something like this:

```
function onKeyDown(event) {
    if (event.key == 'z' && event.modifiers.control){
       //do a thing!
    }
}
```

However, this doesn't work! Weirdly enough, the conditional block never fires. To investigate this, I wrote the following diagnostic handler...

```
function onKeyDown(event) {
    console.log(event.key);
    console.log(event.modifiers.control);
}
```

... and tried it out with various keyboard inputs with some interesting results:

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> key only

```
   Key: control
   Control: true
```

<kbd>z</kbd> key only

```
Key: z
Control: false
```

<kbd>z</kbd> key pressed while holding <kbd>CTRL</kbd>

```
Key: 
Control: true
```

These results suggest that the string returned by `event.key` is different depending on whether the control modifier is held down when another key is typed. Something weird is happening here!

Based on this, how can I detect both of these keys being pressed at the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR**: You can use `event.key.charCodeAt(0)` to detect the strange character codes returned by <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> and other <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+key combinations.

---

As it turns out, the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> combination is [special](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control-Z).

The key being returned in this case...

<kbd>z</kbd> key while holding control

```
Key: 
Control: true
```

... looks like an empty string, because the keycode being passed to the event handler corresponds to the special <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> combination, which results in an unprintable character.

To detect this special character, I modfiied the diagnostic handler...

```
 function onKeyDown(event){
     console.log("Key: " + event.key);
     console.log("Control: " + event.modifiers.control);
     console.log("KeyCode: " + event.key.charCodeAt(0));
 }
```

... and tested the same keyboard combinations as before:

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> key only

```
 Key: control
 Control: true
 KeyCode: 99
```

<kbd>z</kbd> key only

```
 Key: z
 Control: false
 KeyCode: 122
```

<kbd>z</kbd> key pressed while holding <kbd>CTRL</kbd>

```
 Key: 
 Control: true
 KeyCode: 26
```

This means that the special <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key combinations can be detected using an event handler like this:

```
function onKeyDown(event) {
    if (event.key.charCodeAt(0) == 26){ // detect the special CTRL-Z code
        // do a thing! 
    }
}
```

It should be noted that this approach will not work for detecting the control key on its own, since `99` is NOT the character for <kbd>CTRL</kbd>, but rather for `"c"`, the first character in the string `"control"` returned by `event.key`. For that, you'll still want to use `event.modifiers.control`.

Answer (score 3):

Here are a couple of vanilla Javascript solutions that should help you:

### Solution 1

Check which keycode was pressed down and if the shiftkey is down using native the event object.

```
function handleKeyDown(evt) {
    if (evt.which === 90 && evt.shiftKey) {
        // do a thing!
    }
};
```

---

### Solution 2

Keep a global variable for the detecting if the shift key is down and use that in your keydown handler. You'll also need to reset it with a keyup event handler.

```
var shiftKeyDown = false;

function handleKeyDown(evt) {
    if (evt.which === 17) {
        shiftKeyDown = true;
    } else if (evt.which === 90 && shiftKeyDown) {
        // do a thing!
    }
};

function handleKeyUp(evt) {
    if (evt.which === 17) {
        shiftKeyDown = false;
    }
};
```

Comment: The trouble here is that the string returned by `event.key` is actually different depending on whether or not CTRL is held. Shift is a lot easier (and was the first thing I implemented!) because it doesn't change the value of `key`.

Even if you create a global boolean for CTRL and map it to keyUp/keyDown events, you still won't be able to detect the CTRL+Z character by looking for `event.key == 'z'`, because `z` will never be returned by `event.key` so long as CTRL is held.

You could theoretically make your global CTRL boolean toggle each time that key is pressed, but that'd be weird. :)

Comment: That's why I'd recommend using `which` or `keyCode`  rather than `key` as in my example. Each key is represented as a unique number. These attributes are considered deprecated now, but based on what browsers you may need to support they will be the most universally useful, and all future browsers will support them for legacy purposes.

Comment: If I were writing a plain JavaScript handler, I'd be inclined to agree with you! In this case, I'm trying to stick to the event handlers that are provided by the paper.js library, which don't give you direct access to the keyCodes that are spawned by the event handler. But you're right, what you really want in this case is event.keyCode, if it's available!

Answer (score 0):

```
function onKeyDown(event) {
if (event.event.ctrlKey && event.key == "z") {
    //do something
   }
}
```

This should work.